# Is there a quick free way to make a web service?

Tags: web-services

I want to create a quick test web service for a demo. Is there a quick free way to just quickly and easily make a web service that returns one string back when a call is made?

I'm looking free, easy, works out of the box type of thing with minimum setup ... preferably don't want to use any kind of Microsoft tools.

Comment: Try seeing https://github.com/auino/quick-webservice-core-builder to quickly setup a multi-component web service based system.

Comment: @auino Thanks for the response, but the question was already answered and what you have provided doesn't provide what I'm looking for. What you are suggesting requires me to build and deploy the code somewhere but I was looking for something that handles all that out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple HTTP server that returns a response with "Hello, world" on the [node.js home page](http://nodejs.org)

Comment: That would be awesome, but I want it to return back something of my choice.

Comment: Sure.  Just replace the text `"Hello world"` with something else; perhaps a string variable set conditionally with whatever programming logic you need.

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) has a [free web service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) tailored specifically for testing web service calls.  The response given back is based on the parameters passed in.

Comment: This is actually also what I'm looking for. Initially this is what I will use to test but then I will eventually create my own server using node.js above.